# The reciprocal of composite squarefree numbers with an odd number of prime factor vs squarefree numbers with an even number of prime factors

Tags: sequences-and-series

We define $O(N^2)$ as :

the reciprocal of composite squarefree numbers
less than $N^2$,
which has an odd number of prime factors,
where the prime factors
are all less than $N$, but the squarefree numbers itself are all greater than $2N+1$.

Similarly we define

$E(N^2)$ as :
the reciprocal of composite squarefree numbers less than $N^2$,
which has an even number of prime factors, where the prime factors
are all less than $N$, but the squarefree numbers itself are all greater than $2N+1$.

Example :

$O(11^2)=1/(2*3*5)+1/(2*3*7)+1/(2*5*7)+1/(3*5*7)$

and

$E(11^2)=1/(5*7)$

Now will we always have that $O(N^2)>E(N^2)$ ?

I found that it is the case for $N=11$.

Does $O(N^2)-E(N^2)$ converge ?

Comment: With "number of prime factors" , is the number of distinct prime factors meant ? Considering the example, the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Yes. Since it is squarefree numbers we are looking at, the meaning is the same.

Comment: You are right. I forgot for a moment, that only squarefree numbers are considered.

Comment: I wrote a program in PARI/GP and I hope that I got everything right. The code is : z=[];for(n=1,700,a=0;b=0;forcomposite(j=2*n+2,n^2,if(issquarefree(j)==1,w=component(factor(j),1)~;if(vecmax(w)<n,if(Mod(omega(j),2)==0,a=a+1.0/j);if(Mod(omega(j),2)==1,b=b+1.0/j))));if(a>b,z=concat(z,n)));print(z)

Comment: If the code is correct , the positive integers upto $700$ for which we have NOT the desired inequality , are $$[6, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]$$

Comment: So, we can conjecture (but with yet little evidence) that the inequality holds for $N>25$

Comment: Slight correction : For $N\le 5$ , we get equality (both sums are zero)

Comment: For large values , the difference is small , but seems over and over again to oscillate. No indication for a convergence , but neither for a divergence. I would rather guess on divergence.

Comment: Hi Peter. I thought a bit about it and I think that the summation series converges to $0$. This is because it can be written as the difference between 2 summation series which individually both converges to 1. Therefore the difference between those 2 summation series must converge to $1-1=0$.